# How to handle flag occurring multiple times

Tags: java, command-line, apache-commons

I am using the [Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) command line parser and am confused how to implement code to handle a flag occurring more than once in the command line. The current code I have is:

```
if (line.hasOption(tokenOpt.getLongOpt())) {
    exampleArg = line.getOptionValue(tokenOpt.getLongOpt());
    System.out.println(exampleArg);
}
```

This only gets the first occurrence of the flag though. If I change that to a while loop, then it runs an infinite loop. Is there a different method I should use that will get multiple occurrences?

Comment: You want to have something like -r ABC -r CDE ?? and you want to retrieve both ABC and CDE? Is that correct? or do you want -r ABC CDE?

Comment: @Abhi Your first part is correct, if both were receiving I would like to take each string individually and run a the same method on each

Comment: Cant you use `getOptionValues` for this?